# Deleting something off my SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sql-drop

I was using a tutorial on how to create a database and store input info, such as an edit text's information into it and it works great. But I'm just having one problem. The only way to delete that data is to long click the item in the activity with a list view and click "Delete" I want to make it so you can delete that on a button on click. I've tried looking at all the code but I just can't figure it out, being new to databases and what not.So if you could help me out that'd be great. Here's the classes that I believe do the database stuff.

Main one I believe:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import com.name.todo.database.TodoDatabaseHelper;
import com.name.todo.database.TodoTable;



public class MyTodoContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

  // database
  private TodoDatabaseHelper database;

  // used for the UriMacher
  private static final int TODOS = 10;
  private static final int TODO_ID = 20;

  private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.name.todo.contentprovider";

  private static final String BASE_PATH = "todos";
  public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY
      + "/" + BASE_PATH);

  public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE
      + "/todos";
  public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE
      + "/todo";

  private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
  static {
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH, TODOS);
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, BASE_PATH + "/#", TODO_ID);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreate() {
    database = new TodoDatabaseHelper(getContext());
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
      String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

    // Uisng SQLiteQueryBuilder instead of query() method
    SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    // check if the caller has requested a column which does not exists
    checkColumns(projection);

    // Set the table
    queryBuilder.setTables(TodoTable.TABLE_TODO);

    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    switch (uriType) {
    case TODOS:
      break;
    case TODO_ID:
      // adding the ID to the original query
      queryBuilder.appendWhere(TodoTable.COLUMN_ID + "="
          + uri.getLastPathSegment());
      break;
    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }

    SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = queryBuilder.query(db, projection, selection,
        selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
    // make sure that potential listeners are getting notified
    cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);

    return cursor;
  }

  @Override
  public String getType(Uri uri) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
    int rowsDeleted = 0;
    long id = 0;
    switch (uriType) {
    case TODOS:
      id = sqlDB.insert(TodoTable.TABLE_TODO, null, values);
      break;
    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return Uri.parse(BASE_PATH + "/" + id);
  }

  @Override
  public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
    int rowsDeleted = 0;
    switch (uriType) {
    case TODOS:
      rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(TodoTable.TABLE_TODO, selection,
          selectionArgs);
      break;
    case TODO_ID:
      String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
      if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
        rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(TodoTable.TABLE_TODO,
            TodoTable.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id, 
            null);
      } else {
        rowsDeleted = sqlDB.delete(TodoTable.TABLE_TODO,
            TodoTable.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id 
            + " and " + selection,
            selectionArgs);
      }
      break;
    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return rowsDeleted;
  }

  @Override
  public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
      String[] selectionArgs) {

    int uriType = sURIMatcher.match(uri);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = database.getWritableDatabase();
    int rowsUpdated = 0;
    switch (uriType) {
    case TODOS:
      rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(TodoTable.TABLE_TODO, 
          values, 
          selection,
          selectionArgs);
      break;
    case TODO_ID:
      String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
      if (TextUtils.isEmpty(selection)) {
        rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(TodoTable.TABLE_TODO, 
            values,
            TodoTable.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id, 
            null);
      } else {
        rowsUpdated = sqlDB.update(TodoTable.TABLE_TODO, 
            values,
            TodoTable.COLUMN_ID + "=" + id 
            + " and " 
            + selection,
            selectionArgs);
      }
      break;
    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
    }
    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return rowsUpdated;
  }

  private void checkColumns(String[] projection) {
    String[] available = { TodoTable.COLUMN_CATEGORY,
        TodoTable.COLUMN_SUMMARY, TodoTable.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION,
        TodoTable.COLUMN_ID };
    if (projection != null) {
      HashSet<String> requestedColumns = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(projection));
      HashSet<String> availableColumns = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(available));
      // check if all columns which are requested are available
      if (!availableColumns.containsAll(requestedColumns)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown columns in projection");
      }
    }
  }

} 

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.util.Log;

public class TodoTable {

  // Database table
  public static final String TABLE_TODO = "todo";
  public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
  public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY = "category";
  public static final String COLUMN_SUMMARY = "summary";
  public static final String COLUMN_DESCRIPTION = "description";

  // Database creation SQL statement
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table " 
      + TABLE_TODO
      + "(" 
      + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
      + COLUMN_CATEGORY + " text not null, " 
      + COLUMN_SUMMARY + " text not null," 
      + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION
      + " text not null" 
      + ");";

  public static void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
  }

  public static void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
      int newVersion) {
    Log.w(TodoTable.class.getName(), "Upgrading database from version "
        + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
        + ", which will destroy all old data");
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TODO);
    onCreate(database);
  }
}
```

And another one

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class TodoDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "todotable.db";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  public TodoDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  // Method is called during creation of the database
  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    TodoTable.onCreate(database);
  }

  // Method is called during an upgrade of the database,
  // e.g. if you increase the database version
  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion,
      int newVersion) {
    TodoTable.onUpgrade(database, oldVersion, newVersion);
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess so...really new to databases @KenWolf ...

Comment: please dude clarify your question